# Codeigniter file uploading errors not showing for some files

Tags: file-upload, codeigniter-3

I am using codeIgniter file upload library to upload files. and everything is working fine. but I noticed file uploading errors not showing for some files.

I didn't allowed to upload .pdf files, but when I select a small .pdf file "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." error is popping up. and its ok.

But when I select a bigger(my file size is: 24.2 MB) .pdf file and try to upload that file, no any error is popping up.

This is my controller function code:

```
public function import() {

    $import_form_submit = $this->input->post('import_form_submit', TRUE);

    if (isset($import_form_submit)) {

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/temp/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|csv';
        $config['max_size'] = 2048;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['detect_mime'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('import_file')) {

            $data['import_file_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');

            $data['title'] = 'Import customers';
            $data['page_title'] = 'Import customers';

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/main_nav');
            $this->load->view('customers/import');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');


        } else {

            //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            //var_dump($this->upload->data());

            //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }

    } else {

        $data['title'] = 'Import customers';
        $data['page_title'] = 'Import customers';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/main_nav');
        $this->load->view('customers/import');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }


}
```

And this is my view file code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php echo '<h3 class="margin_top_bottom_1rem">'.$page_title.'</h3>'; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
<?php 

if (isset($import_file_error)) {

    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
              '.$import_file_error.'
          </div>';

}

?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="<?php echo base_url().'customers/import/'; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="import">Choose your .csv file to import.</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="import" name="import_file" requiredpp>
                <span class="label label-info">Note:</span> <small class="text-muted">Maximum upload file size: 2 MB.</small>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="import_form_submit"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Import .csv file</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed that issue by chaging max_post_size parameter in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

change this line  `$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|csv';` to `$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|csv|pdf';`